# Location Parameter Link Google Calendar App on iPhone not working

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar-api

This is a very specific question so maybe this is a long shot, but I am very curious if someone could help me out.

I have generated a link so people can add an event to their Google Calender by opening this URL:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=EventTitle&dates=20230418T172700/20230418T192700&location=London&text=Event&ctz=Europe/London

This works well for both desktop and mobile (Android).
However, when I want to open this URL on an iPhone and it opens in the Google Calendar app, the location value is missing.

Any experts here that dealt with this before?

PS: I am aware there is an option within Google Calender to publish an event, but sadly that is not what I am looking for, as the values link will be generated by the system.

Tried putting the location part on different spots within the link.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on this code if you're opening link on any Button Click or any particular event, it's working for me. Also showing location values as **London**.

```
  if let url = URL(string: "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=EventTitle&dates=20230418T172700/20230418T192700&location=London&text=Event&ctz=Europe/London") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            
  }
```